# how to find empty spaces and split it and then store in a variables in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, arraylist

i am reading from a file to my array that's containing a list in the text that i am reading from there is lines that contains two words seperated by empty space 
how can i detect this space so i can store each word in a seperate variable in C++?

Comment: Use std::istringstream and read the words using the stream.

Comment: Plain old `>>` doesn't treat spaces or newlines any differently. You may not have to do anything other than `while (file >> temp) vec.push_back(temp);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::istringstream` defined in the header `<sstream>` to read separate words from a string.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::string a[] =
    {
        "A B", "C D", "E F"
    };

    std::vector<std::string> v;

    for ( const auto &s : a )
    {
        std::istringstream is( s );

        std::string item;

        while ( is >> item ) v.push_back( item );
    }

    for ( const auto &s : v ) std::cout << s << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
A B C D E F
```